# How do I change the values of individual cylinders/points with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have created a node tree with a mesh line to instance cylinders compared to the location of a icosphere. I am struggling with making the cylinders change location individually since at the moment It is moving the entire group at once. How would I go about doing this?

[image: Node tree]

To see what I am attempting to do just move the icosphere along the y-axis.

[image]

Comment: 3.0?  If working in beta, you should probably be mentioning that in your question.

Comment: In your node tree, nothing compares the sphere location with each individual instance location (vertices positions of the mesh line). So it results in one unique value for all. And in consequence they are all shifted the same way. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot move the icosphere with geometry nodes because it is not a point/vertex of geometry nodes.

With geometry nodes you can only move/scale/rotate instances and points/vertices which were created by your (or another nodetree), but not any object. That's why the node is named "object info" node - you can access the information, but you cannot change that object.

So if you want to move your icosphere, you can either do it manually in the viewport or animate it as you want it via keyframes or any other "traditional" method like modifiers or physics or....

Here is an easy example, how you can move the icosphere with a "normal" animation, and depending on that the positions of the instances will change:

[image]

[image]

[image]

you could e.g. give the sphere a rigid body and some bounciness...and with this node tree:

[image]

you will get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at @Chris' answer, this one may be too elaborate.. but here's an option:

[image]

(Some nodes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> collapsed, to save space.)

- It converts a Mesh Line to a Curve to mount the instances.
- It uses Ray Cast to project points sampled from the curve down Z onto the sphere, or whatever is underneath the line.
- Because the points are on a curve, it's a bit simpler to extract a following-rotation for the cylinder instances.

[image]

... But there's a side-effect. As the curve changes length, the spacing between the instances changes accordingly. This may or may not matter to you.. there will be ways to keep the curve-length constant, I'm sure, with some more jiggery-pokery. That would make the tree a bit bigger.

[image]

(Blender 3.0b)

Comment: Thank you all so much! Both of those answers are perfect for what I am doing, but I definitely understand Chris’ answer better lol!

Comment: @pitfall24 Not surprised! :D (That remark is a criticism of me, not you)